# Removing empty list that is returned from find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am facing an error that I am unable to fix although there are similar questions none of the solutions were solving it for me so I decided to ask the question:

I am trying to web scrape a website for an email in the biography of users, if the UserInfo contains an email it should return, but what I am receiving is an empty list [].

I have searched several answers to get rid of the empty lists but none of them were successful

Here is part of the code:

```
email_list = []
email=None
    while email == None:
        if soup.find_all(class_="UserInfo "):
            for my_tag in soup.find_all(class_="UserInfo "):
                emails = re.findall(EMAIL_REGEX, my_tag.text)
                print (emails)
                if emails != []:  # if tag is empty
                    if emails:
                        email = emails[0]
                        print(email)
                       email_list.append(email)
                    print(email_list, "1")
            break
        else:
            email=None
            print("None 1 in User Info")
```

Here is part of HTML: The UserInfo class can be duplicated but all of them could be missing the email:

```
<div class="UserInfo ">
<div>
<div class="ReadMore">text</div>
<a class="UserInfo-readMoreOrLessText">Read Less</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following but didn’t work:

```
                email = [x for x in emails if x]
                print(email)
```

It returned

```
[]
```

I have also tried

```
                if not emails:  # if tag is empty
                    emails.decompose()
                    print(emails)
```

But returned

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decompose'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you set `emails` to `None` if `emails` is an empty list.

```py
emails = None if not emails else emails
if not emails:
    break
# Other logic here.
```